# Kafka-Python Use custom Login Module instead of PlainLoginModule

Tags: python, apache-kafka, sasl, kafka-python

We are using the [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) to connect to our Kafka-instances. To access this we need to be authenticated and it is not plain username/password authentication, we need to get an access_token from an Identity-Service and use it to access the Kafka-instances.

Can someone please help me with the configuration for this in kafka-python? It is same as doing something below in java:-

```
KafkaClient {
  com.mykafka.KafkaIdentityClientLoginModule required;
};
```

Where KafkaIdentityClientLoginModule is the name of the custom login module.

Thanks

#### Note:-

If there is another library which supports this authentication we are open for that.

## References

https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python

http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/